# Can questions be moved from one site to another?

Tags: support, migration

If I post a question to one SE site, say [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and later discover that another SE site (like [Raspberry PI](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)) has better audience for my question, is an easy movement possible? Or should I use the tried-and-tested Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V?

Answer (score 3):

For some sites there is a migration path. From [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) your question can be migrated to:

- [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)
- <s>[ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)</s> (no longer available)
- [Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
- [Tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com)
- [Database Administrator](http://dba.stackexchange.com)
- [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

These migrations can be done by close voting a question (so the question must be off-topic to SO in the first place). Moderators can move questions to other sites too. Just flag the question and explain you want to migrate your question. Make sure though that your question is of high-quality and on-topic for the other site!

Note that migration is only possible for questions asked in the last 60 days.

There is no need to flag if the question has no answers, just delete it and re-post on the other site.

Comment: This only applies if the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow itself though, not when the OP feels the other site has 'better audience'.

Comment: Self-deleting then reposting is fine, it saves the moderators the work. Self-deleting only works if there are no answers anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right. Updated.

Comment: We really need to be able to move questions to Code Review and Software Recommendations, too.

Comment: There is only a fixed number of spots to migrate. I thought they decided the sites on that list according to the stats. If you'd search Meta SE you will find some feature requests for it to change.

Comment: But How do I ask the moderator to migrate the question to superuser or some other stack site ?

Comment: @shirish: Flag your question and ask for migration in a custom flag reason.

Comment: @PatrickHofman how is that done ?

Comment: @shirish: Click on `flag` under your question.

Answer (score -3):

It could be moved, but the SE does not do it. No one really knows the why.

Well, in theory, it is possible and sometimes it even happens, as @PatrickHofman detailed.

In practice, a question migration has so many restrictions, that it can happen only in a very little part of the questions which should be migrated.

As far I know, the "official" explanation is that they try to "defend" the communities from each other. I.e. they try to minimize the influence of the communities. Well, it doesn't look very realistic? Also I can't understand the reason.

However, why they harm their own system, is unclear also to me. I am sad on the so many destroyed content, but unfortunately no one can do anything.

---

Edit: to my largest surprise, the community was so friendly, I've got so welcoming reactions (compared to my similar posts before), that now I think I should not annoy it. I would delete this post, but I won't destroy the worthy comments below. I think a little bit, what would be the best to do.

Comment: ...you alright peterh?  This is very unlike you...

Comment: This... Feels rambley and doesn't really make a lot of sense? First you say migration doesn't happen, then you say it does, then you say it's rare. Then part of your third paragraph don't make any sense... "Well, it doesn't look very realistic?" what's the "it" in this case?

Comment: _"However, why they harm their own system, is unclear also to me. I am sad on the so many destroyed content, but unfortunately no one can do anything."_ Harm ourselves how? From the context, I assume you mean by deleting posts rather than migrating them, but if the posts would be off-topic on the other site, wouldn't keeping/migrating them harm the site more?

Comment: @Makoto Thank you very much! I tought the first comment will be far lesser welcoming. :-)

Comment: @Kendra Yes, exactly this is what I mean. Actually, the count of the question migrations shouldn't be decreased, I think they should be held so high as possible. Question migration means *cross-advertising*. [Check this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/675294/network-wide-stats-for-user-account-creation-after-post-migration). A migrated post means that the OP will know TWO SE sites, and he will have a good experience with both of them. A closed post means that the OP will know only a single site, and they will have a bad experience with it.

Comment: Alright, I think I see where you're coming from- You're saying that, although a question might be off-topic even if migrated, it would at least show the OP another SE site where their question might have an answer? Or are you excluding questions that are off-topic at both sites from this?

Comment: @Kendra The essence of the post, that although the migrations are in theory possible, in practice they happen so unlikely, that we can see them practically non-existent. It would be so wonderful once to talk about this with an SE boss behind a beer! Sad, that it won't ever happen. For me, it is the largest mystery of the SE.

Comment: @Kendra If you really want to know, what do I think the best: a "marketplace SE site" could exist, where everybody can ask *anything*, *but only if it is offtopic on all the existing SE sites*. Anything what is ontopic on any of the SE sites, would be migrated to where it is ontopic. By community votes. And, if enough everywhere offtopic question is gathered about a topic, then these questions could be collected into a new site. This system could replace also the Area51.

Comment: Maybe your expectations are a bit too high.  We don't like migrating crap and 99% of the stuff people want to migrate is crap.  Of the 1% that *isn't*, then you have to do a bit more hand wringing to be sure that it's actually on-topic on the site you want it to go to, or that the other site will be ready to accept it.  Certain sites, like Software Engineers, have outright cut off accepting anything from us, and the same apprehension keeps us from migrating questions to Code Review.  So yes, it *does* happen, just *very* infrequently.  And that's for the best.

Comment: @Makoto The majority of the not crap questions are also closed, even if they could be migrated. Furthermore, if a question is crap, then why we allow it to exist on our site? A crap question is not bad, a crap question is a resource. A potential source of a new visitor, a potential new user, and - after edits & clarification - a potential good question. If the SO can't/won't fix a question because it is crap & offtopic, why it doesn't donate to other sites, where it is only crap, but not offtopic?

Comment: @Makoto I suspect, the root of the problem is that the communities of the Stack Exchange behave so: https://weaponsandwarfare.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/9-wagenberg.jpg While the correct behavior would be this: https://www.salford.ac.uk/__data/assets/image/0008/835496/varieties/lightbox.jpg

Comment: ...Yeah, I'm not gonna speak for other communities.  This is why even *I* hesitate to migrate things, since I don't know if other communities would agree with its quality.

Comment: @Makoto Typically communities tend to react hysterically, defensively, territorially if they get many migrated questions. They should be happy on that. Btw, why it is not possible, that the *target* community votes about a migrated question and not the *source*? Really I am the first, to whom it came into mind? No, I don't think. They why is it not so? I don't think that anybody would know it. Mystery. Secret. Self-mutilation.

Comment: I think an "incoming migrations" review queue has been suggested, but I can't remember if it was just... Never picked up, or if it was explicitly declined... I think it was here on MSO, though, somewhere. I do agree it would help solve some of the trouble of migrations, letting the community being migrated to vote on whether the question fits or not.